# VuetifyJS `nuxt` property not working like `nuxt-link` in NuxtJS framework

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, href

So as per the VuetifyJS documentation [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-btn/#props-nuxt). A button can be turned into `nuxt-link` by adding `nuxt` property, something like below

```html
<v-btn value="home" nuxt href="/home">Home</v-btn>
```

But the problem with this is, this gets rendered server side which is not  how `nuxt-link` works. To verify this, if we use the original `nuxt-link` from NuxtJS framework

```html
<nuxt-link to="/home">
  <v-btn value="home">
    Home
  </v-btn>
</nuxt-link>
```

this gets rendered on client side.

Not sure if this is a bug in VuetifyJS or on purpose. But either way it is not useable for creating `nuxt-link` on VuetifyJS components.

Did I understood this correctly or I am mistaken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `nuxt` prop in the `v-btn` component you should also use `to` prop instead of `href` :

```html
<v-btn value="home" nuxt to="/home">Home</v-btn>
```

Comment: tis is not working also

Comment: @cyril are you using vuetify 2 or 3?

Comment: i am using vuetify 3 when i use it, URL is changing but nothing happen still same page, but i need the "to" because it generate the indicator on the page top, with href instead top it is working but indicator is not working

Comment: In vuetify 3 there's no `nuxt` prop in `v-btn`, you could use href

Comment: Yes it seems to no create an error but useless as it is not present in props